# How do i incorporate multiple divs inside a bootstrap modal-body?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm currently trying to make a single modal with multiple `<div>` tags inside the `modal-body` div.

Example based on what i am doing:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div id="main"> //Main Div or Menu

    <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card">
        <a href="#" id="gen"> //Gen Trigger
         <div class="card-body">
            ... //Content
         </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <a href="#" id="light"> //Light Trigger
         <div class="card-body">
           ...
         </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    
    </div>

<div id="gen-content" style="display: none"> //Modal That Gets Triggered.
 <div class="card-body p-0 m-0">
  <div class="text-right">
   <a class="btn btn-danger btn-back" href="#">Back</a>
  </div>
   Content
  </div>
</div>

<div id="light-content" style="display: none"> //Another Modal That Gets Triggered.
 <div class="card-body p-0 m-0">
  <div class="text-right">
   <a class="btn btn-danger btn-back" href="#">Back</a>
  </div>
   Content
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("#gen").on('click', function() {
    $("#main").hide();
    $("#gen-content").show();
});
$("#light").on('click', function() {
   $("#main").hide();
   $("#light-content").show();
});

$(".btn-back").on('click', function(){
    $("#gen-content").hide();
    $("#main").show();
});
```

Above code works fine, but clicking the `back` button scrolls the page way up to the top. And closing it resets it to the original `<section>`. Is there anything more i can improve with this code? I also think the way i code the content triggers is a bit long.

Comment: insert css or bootstrap plugin link pls

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix by browsing on the jQuery forums. It read:

> use return false; at end of click handler to avoid browser default event on a link. If there is no match to element in href, page will jump to top by default.

I fixed by using:

```
$("#gen").on('click', function() {
    $("#main").hide();
    $("#gen-content").show();
    return false;
});

$(".btn-back").on('click', function(){
    $("#gen-content").hide();
    $("#main").show();
    return false;
});
```